# Spring Boot / JWT application gives access denied in browser but works in postman. Why?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

We are using Swagger and and we need to use the browser in order to display swagger documentation. But For some reason, JWT doesn't allow chrome to access the application and gives access denied.

We followed this tutorial for JWT https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/

Comment: Could be CORS problem

Comment: You need to allow CORS (OPTION) Method

Answer (score 1):

that is cors option method problem. you need to grant access option method
try this on security

```
public class CustomSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
      http.csrf()
        .disable()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll() ....

}
}
```